# Object Array duplicate erasing

Tags: java, arrays, combobox

I need to erase duplicates in `Object example[]`

And Object example is filled like this:

```
final Object example[] = new Object[rowCount];

        try{
            int row = 0;
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1");
            while(rs.next()){
                    example[row] = rs.getString("Name");
                    row++;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DBComboBoxFill error: " + e);
        }
```

And i need it for:
    JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(example)

I know how to do that whit Integers, 1st sort them, then check whit if statement and erase. I don't know, maybe i can do it whit ArrayList, but will the ComboBox get values from ArrayList?

Comment: Simple get unique results from the database `SELECT distinct * FROM Table1`

Comment: Have you looked at the `Set` collections? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: You could use an ArrayList as you said. If you need an array you just need to call the method toArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only column you want is *Name* (which is what it looks like from the code) then you can instead retrieve just that column in the query, and then you can use DISTINCT to avoid duplicates (as suggested by SubOptimal).

That is, change the query from *SELECT * FROM Table1* to *SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Table1* as shown below.

```
final Object example[] = new Object[rowCount];

    try{
        int row = 0;
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Table1");
        while(rs.next()){
                example[row] = rs.getString("Name");
                row++;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DBComboBoxFill error: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you're happy with the answer, would you mind marking it as 'accepted'?

Comment: Would not be fair. ;-) See my comment below the OP's question.

Comment: @SubOptimal, big thanks to you too, haven't forgot about your comment, butonly if you let the '*' in the SQL then it will still have duplicates only in the end, i guess you need to specify the field, so there wouldn't be duplicates

Comment: @qaetosh Right. If there is more then the column `NAME`, you have to.